# What happens to a government's classified information when that world joins the Federation?

Tags: star-trek

What happens to a world's intelligence agencies and their version of classified information when they join the Federation? Does it get passed on to Starfleet Intelligence? Are they allowed to keep it for themselves?

Comment: Federation worlds are still allowed to govern themselves. This presumably includes keeping their own intelligence services alive.

Comment: They don't post it online. It's kept a secret.

Comment: Federation works like interstellar UN, not US.

Comment: I would say more of an EU than a UN.

Comment: Members of NATO don't get plans for F-22 Raptors just because they signed up... You can have some F-35's if you want, but *no one* gets 22s.

Answer (score 8):

This would seem to fall entirely within the bounds of article 1: 0.1 of the Federation Charter (per the [Starfleet Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual)).

> 0.1) The UFP will not intervene in "matters which are essentially the domestic jurisdiction of any planetary social system"

But as we've seen from [TNG: Attached](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attached_(episode)), a world that's still acting under the impression that they need to extensively spy on their neighbours (or their own people) would almost certainly be denied membership.

> **RIKER:** *They will also listen to the reports of the Captain of the Enterprise and his First Officer. And I can tell you right now the First Officer's report will go something like this. **Kesprytt, a deeply troubled world with social, political, and military problems they have yet to resolve. The Kes, while a friendly and democratic people, are driven by suspicion, deviousness, and paranoia.** It is the opinion of this officer they are not ready for membership. Now, the matter of our missing officers.*

Answer (score 2):

In the original series Journey to Babel makes it fairly clear that planetary governments aren't entirely subsumed into the Federation.  They have their own ambassadors and foreign policies with the Tellarites for example having some real differences with the Andorians.
They even retain their own militaries based on Starfleet at that time being specifically an Earth service operating under the Earth Space Probe Agency.  So they probably exchange intelligence data like the agencies of NATO do while holding back some of it.

By the time of TNG the Federation seems to be more consolidated but I haven't noticed any non-humans in Section 31, so the intelligence agencies probably still exist but are even more low profile.